# sorl-thumb doesn't make thumbnails

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, sorl-thumbnail

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but sorl-thumb just uploads the image but doesn't make thumbs...

model.py

```
 from sorl.thumbnail.fields import ImageWithThumbnailsField ,ThumbnailField

 imagen = ImageWithThumbnailsField(upload_to='images',
                                      thumbnail={'size': (75, 75)},
                                      extra_thumbnails={'icon': {'size': (25, 25),'options': ['crop', 'upscale']},
                                                        'large': {'size': (200, 400)},
                                                        },
                                    )
```

setting

```
'sorl.thumbnail',
```

What more do I need? I've followed the documentation.

Comment: Do you have PIL (Python Image Library) installed?

Comment: Yes, sure!!! man, the sorl is working in template but not in the model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the documentation on [when thumbnails are created](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/docs/#when-thumbnails-are-generated)?

You haven't actually explained exactly what your problem is. Edit your original question to show something you are trying to do (along with both the actual and expected results).

EDIT:
As the docs say, your images are not created until they are used. If you want thumbs to be generated when the image is initially uploaded, use the `generate_on_save` attribute like this:

```
ImageWithThumbnailsField(..., generate_on_save=True)
```

Comment: SmileyChris well, i dont know if im wrong but my problem is that sorl dont make thumbs when im trying to upload the file... but is fine...the real good thing here is for me is using in the Template :)

Comment: Edited the comment to reiterate what was already said in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know sorl, but I would say, you need to add `ImageWithThumbnailsField` as a field inside a model

```
class MyImage(models.Model):
    image = ImageWithThumbnailsField(upload_to='images',
                                      thumbnail={'size': (75, 75)},
                                      extra_thumbnails={'icon': {'size': (25, 25),'options': ['crop', 'upscale']},
                                                        'large': {'size': (200, 400)},
                                                        },
                                    )
    name= models.CharField(maxlength=100)
```

[ImageWithThumbnailsField in sorl-documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20090916005737/https://thumbnail.sorl.net/docs/)

Comment: yes man sorry but is there, just i dont copy the model class, but is there :)

Comment: ah, now i understand, what u wanted to say